# Pointers to class templates with different template parameters 

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I got this question on the interview and still have no idea how to solve it:

Let say we have a C++ code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    L<A>* pA = 0;
    L<B>* pB = 0;
    pA = pB;
}
```

What should we add so this actually compiles?

In other words, how should we define `L`, `A` and `B` classes? Please do not use preprocessor's directives.

I have only idea how to solve it:

```
template<class T> struct L {};
struct A {};
typedef A B;
```

Or even simplier with forward declarations:

```
struct A;
typedef A B;
template<class> struct L;
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: "*What should we add so this actually compiles?*" Nothing. What you're trying to do doesn't make any kind of sense. Unless `A` and `B` are the same type (as in your typedef case), there's no point in trying to make this compile. The only thing you can do is subvert the type system, and that's bad.

Comment: A good start would have B inherit from A.

Comment: @BSull add that as an answer (if you dare).

Comment: Can anyone thing of a way to use L<T>::operator= to accept both A and B?

Comment: @ahenderson That won't help, these are pointers.

Comment: It is not what we should do to make this compile, it is what do we want this to mean. L<A> and L<B> are unrelated types so it makes no sense to assign them like that.

Comment: I removed the MSVC specific stuff, please keep it simply and standard in questions. :)

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic how do you know they are unrelated? L, A, B coud be nicknames, and missing code that they ask to produce could show a meaningful relationship.

Comment: Well, OP already wrote about `typedef A B` (I assume you consider these nicknames), so this leaves us with A and B being different types (regardless whether they are related by inheritance). Ruling out `typedef` trick, L<A> and L<B> are unrelated as C++ doesn't support covariance in this context (AFAIK)

Answer (score 9):

No preprocessor directives:

```
/* <-- added line

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    L<A>* pA;
    L<B>* pB;
    pA = pB;

    return 0;
}

*/ //<-- added line

int main()
{
}
```

works fine for me.

Comment: Why the downvote? I followed the requirements to the letter.

Comment: well probably as bad as interviewers can seem from the problem definition, they meant something which didn't include commenting main function away ;)

Comment: @ValentinKuzub if I was asked this during an interview, I'd ask them if they actually wrote code like that. If they did, I'd just leave.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore you and me both (outstanding answer, btw).

Comment: I think the question is not so absurd, though we can argue on its adequacy. It requires lateral thinking (indeed, this is not a normal programming situation) and some knowledge of the language. My answer was initially just following on the joke, but now I think (please forgive the self-promotion) that it is what the interviewers expected.

Answer (score 6):

Easy way out: specialise `L<>` so that `L<B>` inherits from `L<A>`:

```
template<>
struct L<B> : public L<A> {};
```

Answer (score 5):

The `L<A>*` should be assignable from `L<B>*`, meaning that `L<B>` should be a subclass of `L<B>`.

This is not so trivial.  Maybe `A` and `B` should implement some traits concept, which the `L` template can use:

```
template<typename E> struct L : public L< typename E::base >
{
};

struct BASE {};
template<> struct L<BASE> {};

struct A : public BASE {
  typedef BASE base;
};

struct B : public A {
  typedef A  base;
};
```

EDIT -- compiling versio on http://codepad.org/CT3FvmwQ

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Why -1? In theory it should work, even if the code isn't complete hammered down and the problems are trivial to fix. In regards to getting it to compile: The problem is that the typedef in B is in the wrong order. Then it compiles: http://ideone.com/guFVz

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: because I was sure I could make it.